# how to mock this keyword related codes using jest + RTL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new bee to react testing library . Trying to create test file for my `App.js` . Below is my `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nav: [],
            Data: { navigation: [] },
            messages: {
                errors: [],
                infos: []
            },
            entitlements: {}
        }
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        let app = this; 
      Api.getEn().then(data => {
// Its showing in uncovered lines but i have mocked the function on beforeEach method 
            app.setState({ entitlements: data });
            app.setState({
                nav: {
                    name: "Administration",
                    alt: "Administration",
                    link: '/ui',
                    priority: 400,
                    subLinks: links
                }
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        let webhook = <Bla  Data={this.state.Data} nav={this.state.nav} messages={this.state.messages} />
        return (<Switch>
            <Route path="/webhook">
                 {webhook}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                 <Bla  Data={this.state.Data} nav={this.state.nav} messages={this.state.messages} /> 
            </Route>
        </Switch>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

`App.test.js`

```
beforeEach(() => {
Api.getEn()  = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve();
});
});
```

Inside my `componentDidmount` method api call is showing uncovered section though i created mock function inside `beforeEach` method.
Is it because of my code is accessing `this` keyword with reference of `app`like `app.setState`.
I not sure why still the below lines are showing in not covered section. Could anyone please provide some suggestion or guide on this please .

Comment: I have seen many tutorials/samples with enzyme but able to get  it how to achieve the above things using jest/RTL.

Comment: Are you mocking Api.getEn()?

Comment: No I am trying to mock the routing @lissettdm

Comment: @lissettdm i have modified my code /question couldyou please help on me , c

Comment: @lissettdm your previous question is correct im now actually mocking that function call ,but there an issue . I created mockfunction in beforeEach method but when i run test cmd still its showing what ever inside that function is not covered . the same  modified my question. could you please help on this i am looking to solve this more than a day but could not.plz

Comment: Hi, are you using axios or fetch inside Api.getEn()?, because in that case you can mock axios or fecth instead of mocking the entire function.

Comment: I am using fetch inside that getEn method @lissettdm

Comment: OK, I recommend you to mock fetch, window.fetch = jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve(dataYouAreExpeting)), and then you can check if window.fecth have been called

Comment: @lissettdm sure , let me check that and tell advance thanks sir

Comment: @lissettdm - it worked now,thanks sir love u  . you gave some hope..

Comment: Great! your welcome :D